# Filtering for multiple results in batch using IF

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, crash

I was writing a batch file replicating CMD but more customized. What I am trying to do is scan `%input%` for multiple different results leading to different actions. To help you envision what I mean, I tried doing this:

```
set /p input="%cd%>"

if "%input%" == "cls" (

        GOTO reset

) else (

if "%input%" == freespace (

        GOTO freespace

) else (
title %input%

%input%

GOTO A
```

Which just crashes the CMD window running the batch file. Is there anyway I can sort for these two responses (or possibly more) using IF statements? I realize this is SIMILAR to other questions called "using multiple if statements in batch" but they are just not the same format I am trying to put the IF statements in.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes" the window?

Comment: Since you jump after the comparison, you could simply put the IFs one after the other. There is only one else clause with batch and no elseif (But you can use an IF inside an IF). When comparing for equality **both** sides have to be quoted - so use `"freespace"`.

Comment: @Sherpaorc - So that I can learn something, please tell me the purpose of this batch file. My first impression is that it could be used nefariously to make the user think it is `cmd.exe`, but when they type `DIR` the batch file could run something else. If the user enters `DIR` will you run a command to format the disk?

Comment: by crash i mean the window closes without warning or error report. @lit no, this is just a recreation of cmd.exe but with added commands to make things easier. im just having trouble triggering those commands.

Comment: You are missing some closing parentheses...

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be running your batch by clicking on it, which means that you will not see error messages. It's better to run batch from the command-prompt so that the messages will be visible and persistent.

There are at least two problems with the code you have presented.

The first is that you have not closed the parentheses for the `else` clauses so there are two pending close-parentheses at the end of the batch.

format:

```
if x=y (dothis
) else (
 if p==q (dosomethingelse
 ) else (
  dosomethingelseentirely
 )
)
```

The second problem is that `if` is very literal with a string-match. It includes the quotes in the strings-to-be-matched, so

```
if "%input%" == freespace (
```

can never be true as `input` is quoted but `freespace` is not (unlike `cls` in your first `if`)

BTW - `if /i ...` will perform a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple `if` commands to filter multiple results in this particular problem. This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:A
echo/
set "input="
set /p "input=%cd%>"
call :%input% 2> NUL
if errorlevel 1 echo "%input%" is not recognized as a command...
goto A

:cls
echo Reset command, parameters: "%*"
exit /B 0

:freespace
echo FreeSpace command, parameters: "%*"
exit /B 0
```

In this method a `call :%input%` command is directly executed, so if the label exists, then the corresponding code run; otherwise, the `call :nolabel` command returns an ERRORLEVEL equal 2.

Each one of the subroutines ends with `exit /B 0` command, so in these cases the ERRORLEVEL is zero.

If you have any doubt about a particular command, I encourage you the review its `command /?` help screen or search the web looking for a more extensive description...

Comment: This is very interesting, and definitely handy. Not exactly what im aiming to do though. See in your case, when a matching label is found you execute commands and exit, but what I am trying to do with the specific labels i gave you is to use different environments. confusing i know, what i mean is; `:A` is a very "fancied up" environment to execute commands, however `:freespace` has no set variables like `title` or `color`. `:reset` however can be used in your context because it just essentially resets the window by clearing and going to `:A` again.